# SQL update multiple table using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join, where-clause

I have three tables "batch", "batchyield", "batchsop"

```
BATCH

|----------|--------------|----------------|-------|
| batch_id | batch_status | actual_produce | stage |
|----------|--------------|----------------|-------|

BATCHYIELD

|--------------|----------------|
|   batch_id   | actual_harvest |
|--------------|----------------|

BATCHSOP

|--------------|----------------|
|   batch_id   | current_status |
|--------------|----------------|
```

I am trying to update two tables at a time they all are connected with a foreign key
I have written a SQL query for that

```
UPDATE b SET
b.batch_status = 'completed', b.stage = 'flowering', 
b.actual_produce = SUM(byl.actual_harvest), 
bsop.current_status='3' 
from igrow.farm_management_batch b
INNER JOIN igrow.farm_management_batchyield byl ON b.id = byl.batch_id
INNER JOIN igrow.sop_management_batchsopmanagement bsop ON b.id = bsop.batch_id
WHERE end_date < "2022-07-10 00:00:00.000000" and end_date is not null and (batch_status = "running" or batch_status = "to_start")
```

BUT It says the query is wrong

Comment: See the query pattern in Reference Manual carefully. Complete data source (UPDATE .. JOIN ..) firstly, and then SET then WHERE. The syntax with FROM clause belongs to another DBMSs.

Comment: couldn't get it

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement. You should set aggregate in subquery

Comment: You must use a subquery instead of farm_management_batchyield - aggregate and calculate needed SUM(),- and then join it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE igrow.farm_management_batch b
INNER JOIN ( SELECT batch_id, SUM(actual_harvest) actual_harvest
             FROM igrow.farm_management_batchyield
             GROUP BY batch_id ) byl ON b.id = byl.batch_id
INNER JOIN igrow.sop_management_batchsopmanagement bsop ON b.id = bsop.batch_id

SET b.batch_status = 'completed', 
    b.stage = 'flowering', 
    b.actual_produce = byl.actual_harvest, 
    bsop.current_status='3' 

WHERE end_date < "2022-07-10 00:00:00.000000" 
-- and end_date is not null 
  AND b.batch_status IN ("running", "to_start")
```

`end_date is not null` is excess (if previous is true then this is true too), commented.

PS. There is no `end_date` column in shown tables - where it is taken from?

Comment: Akina your answer is ok but Set com before the from and join(of course in SQL Server)

Comment: @hasan Please point me the place where OP tells something about SQL Server..